# Generate file in new task without blocking UI and handle exceptions

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, crystal-reports, task-parallel-library, task

I trying to build **.NET 4.0** application that will generate Crystal Reports files.
I have a working version, but everything is working synchronously - after I click generate button applications freezes for 5 seconds.
Instead of that I would like to show progress indicator that will say that file is generating, but I have problem with my code.

My method that generate report looks like this:

```
public static Task<string> GenerateLetter()
{
    const string destinationLocation = @"C:\Export";
    const string source = @"C:\Test_Report.rpt";
     return Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        if (File.Exists(source))
        {
            var crReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            crReportDocument.Load(source);
            var destinationFolder = new DirectoryInfo(destinationLocation);
            if (!destinationFolder.Exists)
                destinationFolder.Create();
            var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(":", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "");
            var destination = Path.Combine(destinationFolder.FullName, timeStamp + ".pdf");

            var crDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions { DiskFileName = destination };
            var crExportOptions = crReportDocument.ExportOptions;
            {
                crExportOptions.DestinationOptions = crDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                crExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                crExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
            }
            try
            {
                crReportDocument.Export();
                return destination;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new SystemException("Error exporting!", ex);
            }
        }
        throw new FileNotFoundException("Report file not found!", source);
    });
}
```

Method is returning localization of generated file or it throws exceptions if something goes wrong.

In my form I've placed a button and a marquee progress bar. I've attached this handler to button's click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
    try
    {
        Task<string> xx = ReportGenerator.GenerateLetter();
        MessageBox.Show(xx.Result);
        progressBar1.Visible = false;
    }
    catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        ae.Handle(x =>
        {
            if (x is FileNotFoundException)
            {
                var ex = x as FileNotFoundException;
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"File not found");
                progressBar1.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (x is SystemException)
            {
                var ex = x as SystemException;
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Other exception");
                progressBar1.Visible = false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

My questions:

1. How can I fix this? So after I click button UI won't freeze.
2. Can I do this with .NET 4.0 or do I must use 4.5
3. Can I hide progressbar always after task is completed (successful of with exception)? In jQuery I can use deffered.always, is there something like this in C#?

Comment: Try generating your file in a separate thread, that will prevent the UI from freezing.

Comment: @Bayeni - thats why I'm trying to use tasks

Comment: ok. To hide the progress bar after the task completed you can check for Task Status property or IsCompleted property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) is the good point to start with.

You can use them either in 4.0 and in 4.5 .net framework.

In order to ensure that your TPL Task runs on the thread, different from the UI thread, you should use [TaskScheduler.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.aspx) (look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748234/how-to-get-a-task-not-to-be-executed-on-the-ui-thread), for example).

So you should do something like this:

```
Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Your logic here
}, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
.ContinueWith((p) =>
{
     // This will be UI thread
     // p is the parent task

      progressBar1.Visible = false;

     // if parent task has faulted
     if (p.IsFaulted)
     {
          // Do with p.Exception field what ever you want - log it, show it.
          // for .net 4.0 you must read this property in order to prevent
          // application failure

          MessageBox.Show(p.Exception.Message);
          return;
     }

     // Here you know all about the parent task, so you can do the logic you want:

     MessageBox.Show(p.Result);

}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Continuation task will be performed on the UI thread, because of this [TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx) parameter.

In .net 4.0 you also have to handle exceptions from the continuation task. You can do it using try-catch block, for example.

Comment: I had first version build like this, but I want to move generation of file to separate class, this is where my problem begins. I'll try to do normal method and call it inside Task.Factory.

Comment: you can specify any Action<string> as the Task<string> parameter. It can be either lambda expression, or any available method of some class.

Answer (score 3):

`Task.Result` is blocking call, so your UI thread freezes until the task is completed.
Way to solve this is to use new `async`/`await` features. You can use it even in .NET 4.0, but you need to include [async targeting pack for .NET 4.0](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

Make your event handler method async and "await" the task.

```
 private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    progressBar1.Visible = true;
    try
    {
       string result =await ReportGenerator.GenerateLetter();
       MessageBox.Show(result);
       progressBar1.Visible = false;
    }
    catch{
    ........
 }
```

Comment: I accepted @stukselbax answer because it worked using .NET 4.0. Anyway thanks for help :)